# Excel/GSheets count unique versus reoccuring values in dynamic list

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, google-sheets-formula

So I have a large data set of webinar conference attendees - about 30k+ rows. I need to write a function (either in Excel or Google Sheets) to determine if each participant is a first time or returning attendee. The data set is sorted chronologically by event from oldest to most recent. Let's use the simplified version below to better illustrate the business case here.

***Check out the simple sample set here.***

[image]

I considered using named ranges for each of the webinar sets and searching to see if the user exists in that range but given the scale and various webinar attendee sizes that would be tough. I also thought about index-matching the various attendees but because the number of attendees per event is so variable (anywhere from 5 to 500) that too would be frivolous. I feel like I might be missing a relatively simple solution here - please assist! Thanks!

Comment: Why `Person 1, 2, 3...`  is `N/A`. It should new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try on below formula. It will work both on excel and google sheet.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)>1,"Returning","New")
```

[image]

If you need to show `N/A` for first web inner then use below formula.

```
=IF(A2="A","N/A",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)>1,"Returning","New"))
```

Comment: success! truly brilliant sir, thank you! @Harun24HR

Comment: @WaveChappelle Glad to know! Then please mark it as answered (Tick mark).

Comment: To provide further detail here is the reference in Google Sheets for [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en) and [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)