# Excel/GSheets add unique flag to reoccuring values in a dynamic list

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula, google-sheets-formula

As a follow-up to the question I posted previously here - [Excel/GSheets count unique versus reoccuring values in dynamic list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65119032/14485265) I am looking to count unique values in a list of 30k+ Webinar attendees, but this time across multiple criteria.

The logic here is a bit different than a simple COUNTIFS formula as I need to retain all the rows to visualize and interact with in Google Data Studio - so in other words, I need a formula to insert a unique flag ("New" or "Returning") based on the uniqueness parameter.

In short, I need to add logic to this formula to consider different uniqueness:

=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,B2)>1,"Returning","New")

Let's use this simplified data set example for me to explain, notice all attendees are unique except P1 and notice how the values in columns F and G should change by the criteria. Note, I've added borders and colors for easier comprehension.

Link to sample data - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LxirDbk-9w5zu5qqFNoBI9QiK4Za6lFA/view?usp=sharing

[image: sample]

Here's the graph the data is going in:
[image: Graph it is to be visualized in:]

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: When you say _Note, the cells have been merged for readability and easier comprehension_ do mean method in your actual sheet?  If so, while this may make it easier to read, it will make it immensely more difficult to write formulas against

Comment: @chrisneilsen good point, it was just for readability, I've updated the sample set to the way it's actually organized

Comment: I find it much easier to help someone when there is a sample sheet provided - not just an image - so that I don't have to recreate the sample data to verify a solution, and the sheet layout.  Many thanks.

Comment: @kirkg13 here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LxirDbk-9w5zu5qqFNoBI9QiK4Za6lFA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you looking for the formulas for columns F and G, to flag New or Returning, similar to what you have for E?

Comment: Just realised - are the Day values always unique, or could you have Week1/Day1 and Week2/Day1?  In your example they are unique, but I wasn't sure if that would always be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are a few ways to handle this, but to just piggy back on what you already have going in Column E... you can just extend that to handle multiple conditions in F and G by combining your Attendee column with those week and day columns respectively.

This would be the formula for F2 (just drag it down like you did in E)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(arrayformula($B$2:$B2&$C$2:$C2),B2&C2)>1,"Returning","New")
```

This would be the formula for G2

```
=IF(COUNTIF(arrayformula($B$2:$B2&$D$2:$D2),B2&D2)>1,"Returning","New")
```

Again, there are likely many other ways to handle this, but the concept is to use the combined attendee and week or day indicator as a combined unique key to look up against the list itself.

here is a sheet with the solution for you to copy
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DGfVRKnzJM6-tmNPy5GGdD_ca8YAZy0LRB6ci4nDHK0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: absolutely brilliant thank you king bravo

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the earlier answer (I'm a slow worker!) consider this approach, which is basically very similar,  but works to fill the column.

These are three formulas that go in E1, F1, and G1.
In E1:

```
={"Attendee unique";
  ARRAYFORMULA(if(COUNTIFS(B2:B,B2:B,ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B))>1,"Returning","New"))}
```

In F1:

```
={"Week Unique";
  ARRAYFORMULA(if(COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C,B2:B&C2:C,ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B))>1,"Returning","New"))}
```

In G1:

```
={"Day Unique";
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(COUNTIFS(B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,B2:B&C2:C&D2:D,ROW(B2:B),"<="&ROW(B2:B))>1,"Returning","New"))}
```

[image]